# flink streaming maintain state of particular events in the window

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a `Flink` streaming system where I get click stream data.

data format:

```
{"uid":"123", "event_type":"view","payload":{"p1":{"price":23}}}
{"uid":"123", "event_type":"view","payload":{"p2":{"price":25}}}
{"uid":"123", "event_type":"a2c","payload":{"p2"}}
{"uid":"123", "event_type":"a2c","payload":{"p1":{}}}
```

So, here as we see we get two types of events `a2c` and `view`. The difference between these two types of events is in `view` events price is there for all products and in `a2c` only name is there, price is not there.

What I want to achieve is create a consolidated payload out of all the events for a 10 mins window. Also enrich the payloads of `a2c` by getting `price` information from its corresponding `view` event.

consolidated payload once window finishes for each uid:

```
{
    "uid":"123",
    "all":[
        {"event_type":"view", "payload":{"p1":{"price":23}}},
        {"event_type":"view","payload":{"p2":{"price":25}}},
        {"event_type":"a2c","payload":{"p2":{"price":25}}},
        {"event_type":"a2c","payload":{"p1":{"price":23}}}
    ],
   "total":4
}
```

How can I achieve this ?
Basically I have to maintain a state of all the `view` events in the window and then once I get the `a2c` event I have to fetch the price from the state. 
I am not asking for any working solution, just how to maintain the state of all the `view` events in the window.
Also I have some custom Reduce operations.

```
events.keyBy("uid").window(..).reduce(new ReduceCustomFun(..)).uid("..").name("..");
```

in the `ReduceCustomFun`: I am joining 2 events data into the list.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to use a `ProcessWindowFunction` that does all of the window processing at the end of each 10 minute window. Then you would have an `Iterable` containing all of the events (for a given uid) from which to create the consolidated report, and you wouldn't have to concern yourself with maintaining any state.